# Automorphism of tensor product of Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative Hopf algebra over the commutative ring $R$, that is we have comultiplication $\Delta:A\to A\otimes_{R}A$, counit $\epsilon: A\to R$ and coinverse (or antipode) $S: A\to A$. I want to prove that the map $a\otimes b\mapsto (a\otimes 1)\cdot \Delta(b)$ is an automorphism of $R$ algebras of $A\otimes_{R}A$.
I found a similar exercise on Milne's notes on affine group schemes, though my context is just that of commutative algebra.
My first idea was to prove directly injectivity and surjectivity, but I'm completely stuck. Can anyone give me some hints on which is the correct way to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to write down an inverse explicitly using the other operations.

Since $A$ is commutative $G = \text{Spec } A$ is an affine group scheme so we can think about this map in terms of the dual map $G \times G \to G \times G$ of affine group schemes, which is easier to think about. Its action on a pair of $S$-points $g, h : A \to S$ of $G(S)$, for any $R$-algebra $S$, sends $(g, h) \in G(S) \times G(S)$ to some other pair of points in $G(S) \times G(S)$, which we can calculate by restricting the given map to the first and then the second copy of $A$. Restricting to the first copy gives

$$a \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \Delta(1) = a \otimes 1$$

which reveals that the first component of our map is $(g, h) \mapsto g$. Restricting to the second copy gives

$$b \mapsto (1 \otimes 1) \Delta(b) = \Delta(b)$$

which reveals that the second component of our map is $(g, h) \mapsto gh$. Altogether, our map is

$$G(S) \times G(S) \ni (g, h) \mapsto (g, gh) \in G(S) \times G(S).$$

This is much easier to think about: its inverse is just $(g, h) \mapsto (g, g^{-1} h)$.

Comment: Thank you! I had already started going down this road and found the same inverse, though I couldn't actually prove it was in fact the inverse. I'm not used to affine group schemes so I used category theory terminology (natural transformations and so on), but I guess it's the same

Comment: @Avenavolo: the great thing about working in terms of functors of points is that it suffices to verify that the inverse is really an inverse on all points, so you are just doing basically the same computation you’d do in an ordinary group.

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly compute the inverse in the context of morphisms of $R$ algebras? Because while the idea is clear to me, I'm definitely not accustomed to Groups Schemes, so I don't know how to prove the result using only what I know. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Avenavolo: you can translate the map $(g, h) \mapsto (g, g^{-1} h)$ back into a map $A \otimes_R A \to A \otimes_R A$. I didn't do this because it is slightly annoying. It's determined by the property that its restriction to the first copy of $A$ is $a \mapsto a \otimes 1$ and its restriction to the second copy of $A$ is $b \mapsto (S \otimes \text{id}_A) \circ \Delta(b)$ (this is the annoying bit). So in total the map is $a \otimes b \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \left( (S \otimes \text{id}_A) \circ \Delta(b) \right)$. The proof that this is actually the inverse in this language is also annoying.